# Issue with Jmeter Script recorder regarding SSL

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, performance-testing

Trying to record in Jmeter, but when clicking on Start in Http Script recorder, getting below error :

Jmeter - 5.6.2

2024-03-07 15:09:43,994 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Could not read key store keystore password was incorrect; cause: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption., a new one will be created, ensure you install it in browser
java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect

Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
... 47 more
2024-03-07 15:09:43,994 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator$Builder

I have tried re-installing Jmeter a multiple times now. Jmeter certificate is created and already added to Firefox

Answer (score 0):

1. This line:

   > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator$Builder

   means that your JMeter installation is broken somehow, you're [supposed to have commons-text library](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.2/src/bom-thirdparty/build.gradle.kts#L102) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. This line:

   > 2024-03-07 15:09:43,994 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Could not read key store keystore password was incorrect;

   may mean that the auto-generated password from one of previous installations is available in [Java Preferences storage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/core/preferences-api1.html#GUID-66286D3D-67C9-4CF5-8C1E-0BE834F1C6EC) so you might want to clean up this storage, storage location differs depending on the operating system you use
3. Consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o906of55x1n8z2zm8fyj3w9k3lqf8y0c), you're supposed to be [using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
4. There is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/blazemeter-chrome-plugin), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: commons-text jar file is added
Where can I find the Java Preferences storage? and How can I clean up this storage?
I have already tried upgrading to 5.6.3 but its throwing a different error regarding SSL only
Also tried Jmeter Chrome extension but its not recording a few requests